# Ustream within an android app

Tags: android, stream

Are there any libraries or ways to embed/play ustream inside an android application(not in WebView)?

I'm building an app and my client wants his ustream channel to stream inside the application.

I searched stackoverflow for the answer but found all the replies in ref. to WebView.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Have you found a way to add the stream to your app? And why a `WebView` is not suitable?

Comment: Not yet.  I made it run in webview. had to embed it to make it play.  but its laggy.it There might be some clever ways to do it..